# Primefaces DataExporter only prints last column

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

For some reason, when I use the DataExporter, it only prints out the last column. If I exclude that column then it just outputs empty data. This is the same for both PDF and Excel.

I have included both poi 3.7 and itext 2.1.7.
Please help!!!

```
            <p:toolbar>  
                <p:toolbarGroup align="left">

                    <h:panelGrid columns="8" cellpadding="5" >
                        <h:outputText value="Log Type:" />
                        <p:selectOneMenu  id="logTypeSelectMessages" value="#{transactionLogBean.mlLogType}" style="width:200px" >  
                            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select Log Type" itemValue="" /> 
                            <f:selectItem itemLabel="All" itemValue="All" />
                            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Message" itemValue="MESSAGE"  />  
                            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Debug" itemValue="DEBUG" />  
                        </p:selectOneMenu> 

                        <h:outputText value="Message Type:" />
                        <p:selectOneMenu id="reqTypeSelectMessages" value="#{transactionLogBean.reqType}" style="width:200px" > 
                            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select Log Type" itemValue="" /> 
                            <f:selectItem itemLabel="All" itemValue="All" />
                            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Ext Response" itemValue="EXTRES"  />  
                            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Ext Request" itemValue="EXTREQ" />  
                            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Int Response" itemValue="INTRES" />
                            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Int Request" itemValue="INTREQ" />
                        </p:selectOneMenu>
                        <p:commandButton id="refreshBtnMsgLogs" value="Refresh" action="#{transactionLogBean.refreshMessageLogData}" 
                                         update=":transactionLogForm:tabViewGrids:messageTable" ajax="true" />

                    </h:panelGrid>                                        

                </p:toolbarGroup>

                <p:toolbarGroup align="right">

                    <h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="8" >                    
                        <h:commandLink>  
                            <p:graphicImage value="../resources/excel24.png" />  
                            <p:dataExporter type="xls" target="messageTable" fileName="Message Logs" />  
                        </h:commandLink>  
                        <h:commandLink>  
                            <p:graphicImage value="../resources/pdf24-2.png" />  
                            <p:dataExporter type="pdf" target="messageTable" fileName="Message Logs" />  
                        </h:commandLink>                             

                    </h:panelGrid>                                        

                </p:toolbarGroup>

            </p:toolbar> 

            <p:spacer width="10" height="10" /> 

            <p:dataTable id="messageTable" value="#{transactionLogBean.mlList}" 
                         var="m" widgetVar="msgTable" rowKey="#{m.recID}" 
                         selectionMode="single" selection="#{transactionLogBean.selectedMessage}" 
                         paginator="true" rows="20" style="font-size:14px" 
                         rowStyleClass="#{m.rowColour}" >

                <p:ajax event="rowSelect" update=":transactionLogForm:msg"
                        oncomplete="logDialog.show()" />  

                <p:column style="text-align: left; width: 290px">
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        Log Id
                    </f:facet>
                    #{m.logID}
                </p:column>

                <p:column style="text-align: left; width: 80px" sortBy="#{m.logType}">
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        Log Type
                    </f:facet>
                    #{m.logType}
                </p:column>

                <p:column  style="text-align: left; width: 160px" sortBy="#{m.dateTime}">
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        DateTime
                    </f:facet>
                    #{m.dateTime}
                </p:column>

                <p:column  style="text-align: left; width: 105px" sortBy="#{m.requestType}">
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        Request Type
                    </f:facet>
                    #{m.requestType}
                </p:column>

                <p:column  style="text-align: left; width: 110px" sortBy="#{m.extIPAddress}">
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        Ext IP Address
                    </f:facet>
                    #{m.extIPAddress}
                </p:column>
                <p:column  style="text-align: left; width: 130px" sortBy="#{m.serverIPAddress}">
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        Server IP Address
                    </f:facet>
                    #{m.serverIPAddress}
                </p:column>

                <p:column  style="text-align: left; width: 80px" sortBy="#{m.userID}">
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        User ID
                    </f:facet>
                    #{m.userID}
                </p:column>

                <p:column  style="text-align: left; width: 80px" sortBy="#{m.retailID}">
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        Retail ID
                    </f:facet>
                    #{m.retailID}
                </p:column>

                <p:column  style="text-align: left; width: 80px" sortBy="#{m.clientID}">
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        Client ID
                    </f:facet>
                    #{m.clientID}
                </p:column>

                <p:column  style="text-align: left; width: 110px" sortBy="#{m.application}">
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        Application
                    </f:facet>
                    #{m.application}
                </p:column>

                <p:column headerText="Log Message" style="white-space:nowrap; text-overflow: ellipsis; overflow: hidden; text-align: left" exportable="false">  
                    <div style="overflow:hidden; width:300px; float:left; ">
                        <h:outputText value="#{m.logMessage}"/>  
                    </div>                    
                </p:column>                            

            </p:dataTable>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `<h:outputText value="#{m.application}"` instead of `#{m.application}` (place your displayed data inside `h:outputText  value` attribute)